# how to detect changes in database and automatically adding new row to elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

What I've already done:

I connected my hbase with elasticsearch via this tutorial:

http://lessc0de.github.io/connecting_hbase_to_elasticsearch.html

And I get index with hbase table content, but after adding new row to hbase, it is not automatically added to elasticsearch index. I tried to add this line to my conf:

`"schedule" : "* 1/5 * ? * *"`

and mapping:

```
"mappings": {
        "jdbc" : {
             "_id" : {
                 "path" : "ID"
             }
         }
}
```

which assigns _id = ID, and ID has unique value in my hbase table.

It's working well: when I add new row to hbase it is uploaded to index in less then 5 minutes. But it is not good for performance, because every 5 minutes it executes a query and doesn't add old content to index only because of _id has to be unique. It is good for small db, but I had over 10 millions row in my hbase table, so my index is working all time.

It is any solution or plugin to elasticsearch to automatically detected changes in db and add only the new row to index?

I create index using:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/jdbc/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "url" : "jdbc:phoenix:localhost",
        "user" : "",
        "password" : "",
        "sql" : "select ID, MESSAGE from test",
        "schedule" : "* 1/5 * ? * *"
    }
}'
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something called a "river" plugin. There are various around supporting all kinds of databases and even a physical file system. However, the one you're looking for it the [HBase River Plugin](https://github.com/mallocator/Elasticsearch-HBase-River).